# PHP preg_match trouble

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a question about pre_match in PHP.

This is the code:

```
function get_ayalon($input) {
$escaped_input = rawurlencode($input); // RFC 3986!
$ayalon_result = get_URL("http://arabdictionary.huji.ac.il/Matrix.Arabdictionary/Search.aspx?RadioArabic=true&RadioRoot=false&WordString=$escaped_input&NX=903");
$array_of_results_ayalon = preg_match($ayalon_result, "/^/g");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_of_results_ayalon);
echo "</pre>";
die("done!");
}
```

- The variable `$ayalon_result` calls a function that returns the content of a page with cURL.
- In the returned result (of `$ayalon_result`) there is a `^` sign followed by a few digits, and in the bottom of the returned page there is another `^`. The reason I do a `preg_match` is because I want to make the `79156^` in the top of the returned page, for example, and the `^` in the bottom of the returned content disappear.

The problem is that what is returned is just 0, and not an array with content. I guess it's something about the `/^/g` that is not right, but I don't know how to fix it.

Please help me and tell me anything you didn't understand

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have to escape the "/". you should try your regex at http://regex101.com/
Also, could you explain your regular expression further? What should it match to? example?

Comment: pattern must be the first argument

Comment: Could you make it clearer what the output looks like and what part you are trying to extract/remove?

Answer (score 1):

PHP `preg_match` takes the regular expression (regex) as the first argument, the variable to search for the pattern second, and an array to put the matches in third. The "^" is a regex operator indicating beginning of string, so to search for the character Caret, escape it with a backslash. And put parenthesis around the pattern to get all matches. So I think this is what you seek:

```
preg_match("/(\^\d+)/", $ayalon_result, $array_of_results_ayalon);
```

Swap what you have with this and see what you get.

Comment: thanks, but I got it done using another way (substr)